# Citing a short story within a collection within another collection

Tags: citations, citation-style

Its collections all the way down today.

I am usually pretty sure about my works cited pages, but I just ran into something that has me stumped.

I am citing "Araby" from James Joyce's *Dubliners*. However, the only copy I have access to right now is the Barns & Nobel Classics edition, which contains both *Dubliners* and *A Portrait of the Artist as a Young Man*.

So far, this is what I've come up with:

> Joyce, James. *A Portrait of the Artist as a Young Man and Dubliners*.
> Barnes & Nobel Classics, 2004.

and

> Joyce, James. "Araby." *A Portrait of the Artist as a Young Man and
> Dubliners*. Barnes & Nobel Classics, 2004. pp. 249-254.

Ignoring my lack of hanging indent, are either of these correct?

Comment: What sort of document is this for?  For many purposes, you are expected to track the proper source via inter-library loan.   Waiting a week should not matter in most cases.

Comment: @TerryLoring It is for a writing sample needed for a graduate program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How formal your citation must be depends on your audience. Course paper? Thesis? Article for a literary journal?

That citation will allow your reader to find and verify what you have to say.

If what you're writing is scholarly, you might want to find the original publication date, and put (reprinted) in the citation. If it's *really* scholarly you might have to look at the original somehow.

By the way, the text is available at Project Gutenberg. Adding that url will help your readers even if it's not an official source:
https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2814/2814-h/2814-h.htm

Comment: I'm using it in a writing sample required by my graduate program. My particular program asks that we follow the same guidelines as we would for any other course paper throughout undergrad. So it is as formal as, say, a final paper for an American Fiction class.

Comment: Your citation is fine for a course paper. I'd note the (reprinted in). But it will raise a red flag if you write "Barnes and Nobel" instead of "Barnes and Noble".

Comment: Good catch! Admittedly, I was not paying much attention to that at the time. I figured I would have to use a stand-alone copy of the book instead. Cheers!